# ASP.NET - Reading quoted text from local resource file

Tags: asp.net, javascript

i'm using a little javascript in my website for my navigation bar, which is made up of a few ImageButton controls. in the code behind i have this:

```
Dim homeImage As String = GetLocalResourceObject("HomeImage")

imgBtnHome.Attributes.Add("OnMouseOver", HomeImage)
```

and in the resx file, i've tried these, but they don't work: (note the single and double quotes)

```
key: HomeImage     value: "this.src='images/HomeImage.gif'"

key: HomeImage     value: &quot;this.src=&apos;images/HomeImage.gif&apos;&quot;
```

can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong? is it even possible to read "quoted" text from a local resource file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can store quotes in a resx string value.  If you look at the XML that's generated for a resource file, you'll see that the quotes are in the value entries.

However, your script isn't going to work with quotes around it.  Think of it this way - say you wanted to pop up an alert box.  You would do:

```
imgBtnHome.Attributes.Add("OnMouseOver", "alert('hi')")
```

NOT

```
imgBtnHome.Attributes.Add("OnMouseOver", """alert('hi')""");
```

You're passing in a string value for the script, not a quoted string value.  Try removing the double quotes altogether, and leave the single quotes.